# Photo gallery in Yii like zalando site

Tags: php, yii, photo-gallery

I want to create photo view like what is at this address:

http://www.zalando.co.uk/nike-performance-cushioned-running-shoes-grey-n1241a06r-i11.html

Is there any extension in yii for doing it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-cloudzoom/) would be helpful ([demo](http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom)).

there is this [one](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-image-zoomer/) as well ([demo](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/featuredzoomer.htm)).

Comment: Does it have any demos?

Comment: but it is not free, is it a yii extension?

Comment: I think you can download it normally from the extension page, anyway, I added another one, check it out.